# Custom accordion slide effect jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

For those who cant wait here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gq6x5sv7/) :)

So here's what I'm trying to make. I already have this custom multi-level accordion. And what I'm trying to modify about my output is the behavior of the accordion.

Instead of the logic ( When I click on the "header" the "sub-header" goes down as well as the "content" )

**I want the logic to be** ( When I click on the "header" the "header will slide to left and obviously be hide and the "sub-header" will replace the place of the header as well as click the "sub-header" will also let the "content" replace the position of the "sub-header" and "sub-header" also move to left and on closing it will behave vice versa. It will slide to right )

I know my explanation above is a little mess because I don't really know how to say it properly. :) But I have this images below to illustrate more what I'm trying to say.

The **pink** background is the main container and the only place where "header", "sub-header" and "content" will be visible. Outside the **pink** box is not visible to the output.

[image]

A brief view of my jQuery code because I cant post this without putting a little code :)

jQuery:

```
 $('body').on('click', '.title-a1', function() {
        $('.box-a5').slideUp();
        $('.in').show();
        $('.out').hide();
        var currentv1 = $(this).closest('.box-a2').find('.box-a5');
        var triggerv1 = $(this).find('.in');
        var triggerv2 = $(this).find('.out');

        if (currentv1.is(':visible')) {
            currentv1.slideUp();
            triggerv1.show();
            triggerv2.hide();
        } else {
            currentv1.slideDown();
            triggerv1.hide();
            triggerv2.show();
        }
    });
```

Your answers are highly appreciated. Thank you in advance :)

**UPDATED:**

I've got this fiddle from the answer below by **vCode**. This works great and it answers my question but I have this situation where I have many headers as well as sub-headers as well as content. The problem is I don't know how to do it with that kind of situation. I am to new with this kind of custom accordion.

Please check my updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ca7dsedp/2/).

Comment: How do you intend to "close" a section once it has slid out of view?

Comment: Closing would be like when I click the "header" then the "sub-header" would be visible and that arrow in there will like to change to a new icon and by click that icon it will go back to the "header" section. Hope I am saying it properly Sir :)

Comment: I think your HTML code structure can't help you to do what you want .. or you need to use a lot of position : absolute; in css  .. and I don't prefer that way .. did you planed for that before you begin writing your html code?

Comment: Actually Sir the fiddle is the first request of the client then suddenly he change his mind and make it this way. I know I have to change something on my HTML structure but I'm confuse on how the logic will go. I don't really know how to make or start it with the new idea that the client requested.

Comment: may help http://jsfiddle.net/gnLduo61/2/

Comment: Hey @Mohamed-Yousef thanks a lot. I've got some ideas with your fiddle. though its not that perfect for what I want but it gives a big help. Thank you :)

Comment: Hello Sir @Mohamed-Yousef , I have this question :) what if I have many "sub-headers" and each "sub-header" contains its own "contents" how will I do that, when I click on the specific "sub-header" the "contents" on it will be shown. As well as if I have many "headers" and each "headers" contains its own "sub-header" how will I do that, when clicking the "headers" those "sub-headers" that the header contains will only be shown. Anyway thank you for your time Sir. Please patiently help me to achieve my desired output :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For those who have same question as mine I already solve this. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/johnsemblante/toa5psro/1/) out.

Brief view for jQuery code:

```
$('.wrapper-l1 h1').on('click', function () {
    var c = $(this).attr("class");
    $("#" + c).show();

    $(this).closest('div').animate({
        marginLeft: '-400px'
    });
});


$('.wrapper-l2 div h1').on('click', function() {
    var d = $(this).attr("class");
    $("#" + d).show();

    $('.wrapper-l1, .wrapper-l2').animate({
        marginLeft: '-400px'
    });
});

$('.wrapper-l2 div .rights-a1').on('click', function() {
    $('.wrapper-l1, .wrapper-l2').animate({
        marginLeft: 0
    });
    $('.wrapper-l2 div').fadeOut();
});

$('.wrapper-l3 div .rights-a2').on('click', function() {
    $('.wrapper-l2, .wrapper-l3').animate({
        marginLeft: 0
    });
    $('.wrapper-l3 div').fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `.animate()` function combined with some css to accomplish this.

#### HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="level level-1">Header <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>

    </div>
    <div class="level level-2"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
Sub-Header <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>

    </div>
    <div class="level level-3"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>

        <ul>
            <li>Content</li>
            <li>Content</li>
            <li>Content</li>
            <li>Content</li>
            <li>Content</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.row {
    white-space : nowrap;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.level {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 900px;
    width: 200px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
ul {
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
i {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

#### jQuery

```
$('i.fa-chevron-right').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('div').animate({
        marginLeft: '-200px'
    });
});

$('.level-2 > i.fa-chevron-left').on('click', function () {
    $('.level-1, .level-2').animate({
        marginLeft: 0
    });
});

$('.level-3 > i.fa-chevron-left').on('click', function () {
    $('.level-2').animate({
        marginLeft: 0
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/voveson/ca7dsedp/

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer Sir.

I have this question. what if I have many "sub-headers" and each "sub-header" contains its own "contents" how will I do that, when I click on the specific "sub-header" the "contents" on it will be shown. 

As well as if I have many "headers" and each "headers" contains its own "sub-header" how will I do that, when clicking the "headers" those "sub-headers" that the header contains will only be shown.

Anyway thank you for your time Sir. Please patiently help me to achieve my desired output :) Thanks

Comment: I have this updated fiddle of yours. http://jsfiddle.net/ca7dsedp/2/

When I click header1 it will only show subheader1 and also when I click subheader 1 will only show content1. Thanks Sir